# Dates for entries are in different language

Tags: entry, structure, datetime, admin, channels

When the user wants to edit the Post Date or Expiry Date of an entry (channel/structure), the calendar is in Welsh language.
I have no clue how this happened.

How can I change this?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to that user's account settings, then click on the "Preferences" tab, I'm guessing they have their "Formatting Locale" setting set to Cymraeg.

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you for that!